# Clone all projects from cgit

Tags: automation, download, cgit

I have to download all projects that are hosted on some [`cgit`](https://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/about/) instance. There are several hundreds of repositories, so it is tedious to do this manually.

How can it be done?

Seems that it is possible to do it with `curl` by parsing pages one by one. By is there more convenient interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any official or convenient API for CGit to export/clone all its repositories.

You can try [those alternatives](https://dabase.com/e/09020/):

```
curl -s http://git.suckless.org/ |
xml sel -N x=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot; -t -m &quot;//x:a&quot; -v '@title' -n |
grep . |
while read repo
do git clone git://git.suckless.org/$repo
done
```

Or:

```
curl -s http://git.suckless.org/ | xml pyx | awk '$1 == "Atitle" { print $2 }'
```

Or:

```
curl -s http://git.suckless.org/ | xml pyx | awk '$1 == "Atitle" { printf("git clone %s\n",$2) }' | s
```

I suspect this work for *one* page of Git repositories as listed by CGit: you might still have to repeat that for *all* subsequent Git repositories pages.